# Is there a way to continuously paging large amounts of data?

Tags: typescript, oracle, fastify

I am working on a project in Android Studio that requires to paginate a very large amount of data.

It's about 30,000 pieces.

```
fastify.post<{Body: ProductPagingBody}>(
    //Route
    '/list_paging',
    {
        schema: {
            body: ProductPagingBodySchema
        }
    },
    async(request, reply) => {
        const { store_code } = request.user
        const { page_no, page_size } = request.body
        
        try {
            const result: ProductList = await Product.getProductList(store_code, page_no, page_size)

            if (result) {
                reply.send(result)
            }else {
                reply.send({
                    code: 404,
                    error: 'ProductInfo Error',
                    message: 'No matches productInfo'
                })
            }
        } catch (e) {
            reply.send({
                code: 401,
                error: 'ProductInfo Error',
                message: 'Failed to get productInfo'
            })
        }
    }
)
```

I request product list with paging number and paging size.
But, when the 4th request, no more requests have been returned.
If restart again, it will work normally.
But it stops at the same place.

Page 1, 2, 3 in a row... I would like to know if there is a good way to deal with this when you continue to request to.

--------------------------------Add

```
static async getProductList(page_no: number, page_size: number): Promise<ProductList> {

    const rawData: ProductList = await getManager().query(
        `SELECT 
            ...
        FROM
            (
                SELECT /*+ INDEX(T1 PK1) */
                    ROWNUM AS RNUM, T1.*
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ...
                            FROM (
                                ...
                            ) H
                            ORDER BY H.BARCODE
                    ) T1
                WHERE
                    ROWNUM <= ${page_no * page_size}
            ) T2
        WHERE
        ${page_no == 1 ? page_no : (page_no - 1) * page_size + 1} <= RNUM`
    );

    const productList: ProductList = rawData

    return productList;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your get Product List code?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Thanks you for your reply. Add product list code.

Comment: "But, when the 4th request, no more requests have been returned." Can you please explain this? Are you saying your service stops responding after you call it 3 times? Or that it returns no data after page 3?

Comment: @JohnWu  The service stops responding after call it 4 times

Comment: What oracle version are you using?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to troubleshoot the issue. You need to isolate the problem more. Confirm that the client is sending the request, and that is correct; confirm that the request makes it across the network; confirm that your web server is receiving it; confirm that it is being passed to the proper handler; that the handler is invoked; that your code is running; that the database is receiving the SQL request. You should be able to check each step is happening from various kinds of logs or traces.